# C# Can't connect to database locate in my server debian

Tags: c#, mysql, debian, static-ip-address, database-connection

I have a problem with my mysqlconnection here is my code in c#

```
 public Bdd()
    {
        this.connection = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=192.168.205.1; DATABASE=bdassistnounou; UID=root; PASSWORD=root");

    }
```

here is my configuration on my VM debian :

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.205.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.205.0
broadcast 192.168.205.255

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

The adresses of my vm users (win7) is 192.168.205.12
I tried to ping to my users and debian it's works same in the opposite
And if I put 192.168.205.1 on firefox ( In my vm users) i have access to mysql.. 
So please, someone can give me a solution ? I'm in a dead end..

Comment: How do you connect through Firefox? Are the connections strings identical? Are there any error codes/messages from C#? What is the rest of your C# code?

Comment: Perhaps port 3306 is blocked on your server? Try to telnet to this port and see if you get through.

Comment: @Johan: as he can connect with Firefox, I did assume that wasn't the issue. Unless MySQL was set up to use another port - in which case that would be see in the "Firefox" connection string.

Comment: Firefox + mysql connection = confusing to me :) I just assumed some phpmyadmin would appear when browsing to his server via FF.

Comment: I did assume that PHP was used - but there may be other languages used. Whatever language - there must be a connection string somewhere.

Comment: @PaulF On firefox in the url I write the adresse ( 192.168.205.1) and i have access to mysql, so my users have acces to my debian servers, but when i tried to launch my application.it's says : Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Comment: Typing the URL into firefox will only give you access to a web page - if the webpage allows access to a MySQL database then there must be some code on that page, in PHP or some other language. You need to find out what connection string that uses.

Comment: Please be aware of possible hostname restrictions for database users on mysql. Possible values are for example 'localhost' and '%'. If your root is restricted to localhost, going directly to the IP of the mysql will give you access (assumption: phpmyadmin or the like is running). But access from within your c# app will not be allowed. As the hostname is not allowed. Try changing this to '%' (any host) and see if that resolves the issue. (keep in mind my first comment about port 3306)